# Finding sign function result

Tags: functions

How can we get the following sign function result for example if $x=-5$, $\lambda=10$ and $n=5$? what if $x=1$, $\lambda=10$ and $n=5$?

$$\operatorname{sgn}(x)(|x|-\lambda/n)+$$

what does this sign function exactly do? Anyone has any idea?

Comment: what does + symbol means here? and how does lamda effects on the answer or the signs of this function?

Answer (score 1):

**By definition it  extracts the sign of a real number for example**

**$\operatorname{sgn}(-2)=-1$**
**$\operatorname{sgn}(2)=+1$**
So when $$ x>0$$ you have  $$  (x-\frac{\lambda}{n})$$
And when $$ x<0$$ you have   $$  -(-x-\frac{\lambda}{n})$$

Comment: It seems reasonable but what about positive subscript symbol at the right part of the formula?

Comment: where did you find that ,check your textbook it might explain  what that means , it might just be a mistake never seen that before

Comment: It was in a kind of regression method. I am sure that it's not a mistake